# Access data from HTML file (Ionic Framework)

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm new to JavaScript and [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com) and I have following problem.
I'm trying to access data from an external HTML file using `getElementsByTagName()`, because I want to get some text from the HTML file and show it in the App's list-view but it's not working.

I'm using following code in my controllers.js file:

```
//General
.controller('generalCtrl', function($scope) {
    //Create Arrays
    $scope.items = {};
    $scope.item_names = {};

    $scope.siteDiv = $('<div>');

    $scope.siteDiv.load('website.php #somediv', function(){
        $scope.item_names = $(this).document.getElementsByTagName("a");

        //create list view
        for(i=0; i<$scope.item_names.length; i++) {
            $scope.items[i] = { title: $scope.item_names[i], id: i };
        }
    });
})
```

It seems like the array `$scope.items` is empty because everything worked when I defined it manually. But I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

I hope someone can help me with that problem. Thanks for your attention.

**Edit 1:**

I've added a try-catch function which returned following error: 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable:$'. Also it says that the `%scope.item_names` variable is undefined, so it seems to be unable to load the site. I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: First try wrapping your code with error catching blocks in order to identify whether or not the application is properly extracting and passing data to where it needs to flow; specifically around the code that grabs the anchors and the for loop. You might also want to make sure your scope variable isn't null/empty or contains an object which you might not be accessing properly. (Wishing I had my ionic setup next to me to provide with a proper answer).

Comment: I've added a try...catch function to the code now it returns following error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $". Also it's unable to load the view at all, it jumps back to the default view.